# Could someone translate this handwritten letter?

Tags: перевод

Would someone be able to translate this letter I found. Some of the characters I just don't recognise, I've been learning using typed letters.

Comment: Where is the letter?

Comment: Sorry thought it was there, I've uploaded it now

Comment: Funny; just this morning, I ranted in Meta about the unfairness of closing handwriting requests as off-topic, and now I have to say that expecting people to type up a rather long doggerel poem, written in a mostly tidy handwriting, and, if I understand correctly, translate it while they're at it, is, shall we say, a bit overkill. Could you perhaps post a version of the scan with the words you can't make out highlighted?

Comment: Sorry. I'll take it down. I'm new to learning the language and I couldn't make out some of the different letters, whether neatly written or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since stackexchange is not a simple translation service, here is this letter in typed letters, so you could translate it by yourself:

Алкоголь Скорая *Алкоголь (stroke through)* Антон.
А тема очень уж проста
Пишу я с чистого листа
Антоха парень просто класс
И про него сейчас рассказ
Решил немного выпить пива да
И вот какая ерунда
что скажем по секрету
закинули в карету
Антоху в скорой помощи
Теперь желудок полощи
А так по сути и конец
Ну ваш Антоха молодец!

hope this helps you